# Passing Integer Value to Broadcast Receiver class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-timepicker

I am trying to get start time and stop time from user using Time Picker in one class and then passing this time to the broadcast class.

But when I am checking whether the values of the start time and stop time is reached in the Broadcast Receiver class by using a toast message, I am not able to get the required start time or stop time that is passed.

CODE [Main Class]:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);
    initialize();
    alarmIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Settings.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmRepeat();              
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.startTime :
        // Process to get Current Time
        startHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        startMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog tpd1 = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                            int minute) {
                        // Display Selected time in textbox
                        eStart.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        startHour = hourOfDay;
                        startMinute = minute;
                        alarmIntent.putExtra("startHour", startHour);
                        alarmIntent.putExtra("startMinute", startMinute);//passing these variables to Broadcast class
                    }
                }, startHour, startMinute, false);
        tpd1.show();

public void alarmRepeat(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

**Broadcast Class :**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startHour = intent.getIntExtra("startHour", 0);
    stopHour = intent.getIntExtra("StopHour", 0);

    Toast.makeText(context, startHour + ":" + startMinute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Program explanation**: I have passed startHour and startMinute from the onTimeSet method in the main class to broadcast class.

In the Broadcast Class I am storing this startHour and StopMinute in the variables as defined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating the alarm in `onCreate` and then updating your information in `onClick`. I'm pretty sure your `pendingIntent` declaration needs to be after you've supplied the information to `alarmIntent`.

Edit: I would recreate `pendingIntent` immediately after updating `alarmIntent` and then call `alarmRepeat()` again. Personally, I would put the assignment of `pendingIntent` inside the alarm method and pass `alarmIntent` in as a parameter, but that's a stylistic choice.

As long as the pending intents are the same (not including extras added to the  intent inside it) alarmmanager will override any existing alarm with the new alarm

Comment: Yeah, basically that is the dilemma. But then how can I call the broadcast class from the onClick() method?

Comment: I'm not sure what `alarmRepeat()` does, so I'm not sure why you need to create the intents in your `onCreate()`. Are you broadcasting the intent with `AlarmManager`? If so, you can overwrite your existing alarm in `onClick`. I'm on the bus right now but I can write some sample code when I get home

Comment: I have edited the question and added the alarmRepeat() function. If I will call the Broadcast intent in the onClick() function then where should I call because there also the the value of startHour and startMinute is defined only after the Time picker set the values.

Comment: I actually didn't get it. If I am not wrong then you are saying whenever I am adding extras inside the intent I should call pendingIntent() and alrmRepeat() again?

Comment: That's right. Creating your alarm again with the same basic pending intent will overwrite your existing alarm. So, assuming you need to create the alarm before the user inputs anything, that would be the way to go. If you don't need to create the alarm until the user inputs something, then I would only put it in `onTimeSet`.